# Validation error on "baked" date field , CakePHP 3

Tags: validation, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

I have a "baked" cakePHP-3.0.0 page which has a field defined as

```
date_of_birth date DEFAULT NULL
```

in TABLE `users`.

When I click the Submit for the `add` function I get

> Warning (2): preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Validation\Validation.php, line 763]
>
> Code Context
>
> ```
>  protected static function _check($check, $regex)  
>  {  
>
>
>       if (is_string($regex) && preg_match($regex, $check)) {  
>
>
>
>           $check = [  
>              'year' => '2014',  
>              'month' => '01',  
>              'day' => '01'  
>          ]  
>          $regex = '%^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|    [2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))([- /.])(?:0?2\1(?:29)))|(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?    \d{2})([- /.])(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\2(?:31))|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])    \2(29|30))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\2(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))))$%'
> ```

Any suggestion on how to fix ?
    The stack trace is

```
preg_match - [internal], line ??    
Cake\Validation\Validation::_check() - CORE\src\Validation\Validation.php, line 763  
Cake\Validation\Validation::date() - CORE\src\Validation\Validation.php, line 346  
Cake\Validation\RulesProvider::__call() - CORE\src\Validation\RulesProvider.php, line 53  
Cake\Validation\RulesProvider::date() - CORE\src\Validation\ValidationRule.php, line 138  
Cake\Validation\ValidationRule::process() - CORE\src\Validation\ValidationRule.php, line 138  
Cake\Validation\Validator::_processRules() - CORE\src\Validation\Validator.php, line 554  
Cake\Validation\Validator::errors() - CORE\src\Validation\Validator.php, line 128  
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::_validate() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 185  
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE\src\ORM\Marshaller.php, line 341  
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 1899  
App\Controller\UsersController::add() - APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 48  
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 406  
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 114  
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 87
```

Comment: Can you please delete those comments and instead update your question? Also, please post the validation rule that got baked.

Comment: The "application" was completely generated via "cake bake all _tablename_ ", the particular table field was "date-of-birth date DEFAULT NULL".    I am not aware of any validation rule that got baked.

Comment: I also get a very similar error for "datetime DEFAULT NULL" variables in the generated form when I attempt to update via Edit.  "expects parameter 2 to be string, array given ".

Answer (score 0):

Please read the answer to 
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5611#issuecomment-69254634

The problem has been fixed, please update your cakephp version using "composer update".

Note that you will have to use **`dev-master`** in composer until a new release has been tagged.